# Scheduled Firebase Functions with c#

Tags: c#, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.MyFunction = functions.region('europe-west1').pubsub.schedule('every 10 hours from 00:30 to 23:10')
    .timeZone('Europe/Madrid')
    .onRun(async (context) => {

            'do something'

    });
```

I would like to migrate to c# but I can't find how to do it

I see the documentation and the examples but I don't see how to do it in:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/main/functions

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase supports only NodeJS for Cloud Function. If you want to use C# then you'll have to deploy to Google Cloud Functions directly. You can use `gcloud` CLI to do so.

Checkout [this codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-functions-csharp#5) for a simple example using pub/sub triggers.

Comment: but I don't know if I need pub/sub triggers:

would i have to make a cloud function in c# and then create a cloud scheduler that calls that function?

Comment: @Angelru yes, the linked codelab and [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub) should help.

Comment: But do I need pub/sub? I do not understand that.

Comment: @Angelru not really, you can also just use [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler) and invoke your HTTP function with it.